# Fetch records with distinct value of one column along with max of another column

Tags: db2

We have a requirement like fetching all the columns of a table by filtering distinct values of one column along with the max value of another column.

Example:

```
Table A

id name qty
__ __ __

1 Dinesh 10
2 Ramesh 8
3 Dinesh 2
4 Ganesh 3
5 Ganesh 20
```

Here fetching distinct name along with max(qty);

Expected output:

```
1 Dinesh 10
2 Ramesh 8
5 Ganesh 20
```

Can anyone say how to achieve this in DB2 query?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a correlated sub-query to do this.

```
SELECT T.id, T.name, T.qty
FROM tableA T
WHERE T.qty = (
    SELECT MAX(qty)
    FROM tableA
    WHERE name = T.name
)
```

However, note that if there is another record with the same name and maximum qty (such as `6 Dinesh 10`) then both records will be returned.  This can be resolved be writing the query slightly differently:

```
SELECT T.id, T.name, T.qty
FROM tableA T
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tableA
    WHERE name = T.name
        AND qty > T.qty
        OR (id > T.id AND qty = T.qty)
    )
```

Comment: He is saying that he needs the distinct values, which isn't the first case. Also in the second case doing it your way, can't you just use a 'distinct' on the select?

Comment: @MazarD - Each row has a unique id, using `DISTINCT` would therefore return every row.  I see what you are saying and would work if only the name and qty columns where required

Answer (score 1):

//Edit: After the acatt comment I understood the requirements...

Another option would be:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, t.qty
  FROM tableA t
 WHERE (t.name, t.qty) in (
    SELECT q.name, max(q.qty)
    FROM tableA q
    group by q.name
 )
```

Also considering that all the rows with same name and qty would be returned

Comment: I am getting `SQLCODE = -122, ERROR: COLUMN OR EXPRESSION IN THE SELECT LIST IS NOT VALID` while executing the query as you mentioned above.